# I'm working with 4 artboards in .ai, 4 diecut shapes on each board need to line up with the others

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I am working on retail packaging. Picture something along the lines of a iphone screen protector package that opens like a book.

A) Front of package has a diecut shaped window on the front. 
B) On the other opposite side of the front flap contains a second diecut shape window.  Both have different yx locations.

C) Inside the package has a duplexed card that gets inserted into the package. The product sticks to each side and shows through the two diecut windows.

How do I make sure the insert cards line up perfectly to the front / inner front windows.

I will update if I can think of a better way to explain this.

Comment: just draw a diagram of what your problem is and upload it - sounds sorta cool

Comment: Haven't you measured location for the placement needed? What does this have to do with artboards? Are you printing this yourself or having them commercially printed? Why do things on separate artboards need to line up to each other (beyond proper print specifications)?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like you may be better off using layers instead of artboards. You can use your existing file to do this. Simply create 3 new layers (so you have 4 total), then name them accordingly so you stay organized.

Then, with each respective layer selected, move the art from its artboard onto the original artboard, making sure it's on its own layer. Do this for each of the 4 pieces you need. Then you can line them up as needed. Use guides for precise placement if necessary.

If you need to output, you can turn off 3 of the layers, print the visible one, then do the same for the other three. You can have Illustrator print crop marks for you, or make your own on the artboard. These will also help you line up your artwork.